# missing } in xml expression and exce_next

Tags: javascript

my javascript function is throwing this error

```
var cycles = 0;
var exec_next = null;

function timer_interrupt() {
cycles++;
 if (exec_next) {
    var cmd = exec_next;
    exec_next = null;
    cmd();
  }
 }
```

using firebug it says the } should be at the end of the cycles++; what to do? I don't have any xml script being displayed?

it is being included in my template like this

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="mysript.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Add `type="text/javascript"` to your `<script>` tag and remove the `language` attribute.

Comment: Are you omitting something relevant? Is there an AJAX request involved that might be returning XML?

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?